# Why merging with DASK Delayed takes extremely more time than merging with DASK built-in command?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, dask, dask-delayed

I want to merge a large pandas dataframe with shape of df1.shape = (80000, 18) to a small one with shape of df2.shape = (1, 18) on a column called "key". Here is the time performance using dd.merge:

```
ddf1 = from_pandas(df1, npartitions=20)
ddf2 = from_pandas(df2, npartitions=1)
start = time.time()
pred_mldf = dd.merge(ddf1 , ddf2, on =['key'])
print(pred_mldf)
t0 = time.time()
print("deltat = ", t0 - start)
```

And the result is deltat = 0.04.

Then I started implementing this using dask delayed in this manner:

```
def mymerge(df1, df2, key):
    pred_mldf = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = key)
    return pred_mldf

start = time.time()
pred_mldf = dask.delayed(mymerge)(df1, df2, ['key'])
pred_mldf.compute()
t0 = time.time()
print("deltat = ", t0 - start)
```

And the results is deltat = 3.48.

My hypothesis is that I need to reach the same time performance with two approaches. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not actually executing the merge in the first code block. Dask generally uses a programming model called lazy execution or lazy evaluation. You may want to explore the docs https://tutorial.dask.org/01x_lazy.html

Comment: @NickBecker Thanks. You made good point! I edited my question based on your comment. But the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nick Becker pointed out in the comment, right now your first code block only defines the merge, but does not execute it (while the second code block does), so adding `.compute()` should give a different merge time:

```py
ddf1 = from_pandas(df1, npartitions=20)
ddf2 = from_pandas(df2, npartitions=1)
start = time.time()
pred_mldf = dd.merge(ddf1 , ddf2, on =['key']).compute()
print(pred_mldf)
t0 = time.time()
print("deltat = ", t0 - start)
```

Another reason for different execution speeds is that in the second code block you are passing the complete `df1` to the delayed function. If `df1` is large, then it might be a bit more fair to split it into 20 chunks (like in the first code block) and pass those individually to the delayed function.